# Android Gesture Detection

Tags: android, gesture

I'm trying to develop an android application that is basically for drawing shapes.I want the user to make gesture on the screen and the shape that is more closely matching to gesture should be drawn on the screen.
In my application,I can detect the gesture that is being performed on the screen like circle,line,rectangle etc. but there is some problem with my code.It actually detects the gesture and draws the respective shape but it happens only once.

For example. If I draw Line on the screen then line is drawn on my view but after that If I draw circle or rectangle etc then gesture is recognized but the shape is not drawn there.

Here is the full code of that

```
package com.pck.ShapeMaker;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.Prediction;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GestureDetection extends Activity {
    private GestureLibrary gLib;    
    private LinearLayout l1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gesture);
        l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playArea);

        gLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!gLib.load()) 
            finish();   
        GestureOverlayView gesturesView = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        myGestureHandler handler = new myGestureHandler();      
        gesturesView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(handler);


    }

    class myGestureHandler implements OnGesturePerformedListener{

        public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView gestureView, Gesture gesture){
            ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gLib.recognize(gesture);        


            if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 1.0) {
                String action = predictions.get(0).name;
                if ("l".equals(action)) {
                    Line line = new Line(getApplicationContext(),20,230,200,230);
                    l1.addView(line);
                } else if ("r".equals(action)) {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(getApplicationContext());
                    l1.addView(rect);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "rect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if ("t".equals(action)) {
                    Triangle tri = new Triangle(getApplicationContext(), 300,300,250, 350, 350, 350);
                    l1.addView(tri);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "trianlge", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if ("c".equals(action)) {
                    Circle c1 = new Circle(getApplicationContext(),50,50,30);
                    l1.addView(c1);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "circle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if ("d".equals(action)) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "diamond", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }




            }

    }
}
```

Comment: did you solve your problem?I have the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code will produce an ever-increasing number of views within the LinearLayout. Is that what you intended? If not, you could try removing the obsolete views from the layout before adding the new one. The problem may be that there is no space in the layout for subsequent views after the first one is added.

Also, dynamically adding views like this, seems like an odd way to draw graphics. Why not define a single custom view to cover all types of drawing and include that statically in XML? Your onGesturePerformed() method would then call some method of your view to specify the type of drawing to be performed, then call invalidate() to trigger redrawing. The onDraw() method of your view would then draw whichever graphic was just specified.